# Implementing SwiftUI-like Sheet Presentation (or full screen view) in Jetpack Compose and Navigation Components in Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am an iOS developer currently working on an Android project using Jetpack Compose. I am trying to implement a full-screen view similar to SwiftUI's sheet presentation, but I'm facing some difficulties. I would appreciate it if someone could guide me in the right direction.

[image]

Here are my two questions:

1. Is there a feature in Android (particularly in Jetpack Compose) similar to SwiftUI's sheet presentation?
2. When attempting to display another view on top of the current one, should I still utilize NavHost, Navigation Components, and Navigation Controller?

For the first question, I've searched for something akin to SwiftUI's sheet presentation in Jetpack Compose but haven't found a direct equivalent. I'm considering displaying the **`DetailScreenCompose`** on top of the **`HomeScreenCompose`** as a full-screen alternative if such a feature doesn't exist in Android.

Regarding the second question, my project involves two main Compose functions: **`HomeScreenCompose`** and **`DetailScreenCompose`**. Within **`HomeScreenCompose`**, there is a **`HeaderCompose`** with a gray background, housing a gear icon button that triggers the display of **`DetailScreenCompose`** in full-screen mode. **`DetailScreenCompose`** presents plain text without any internal navigation. Essentially, I aim to display **`DetailScreenCompose`** in full-screen mode upon pressing the settings icon button and dismiss it upon tapping the less than icon button.

Given this context, should I still rely on NavHost, Navigation Components, and Navigation Controller to implement the transition to **`DetailScreenCompose`**? Should I include the NavHost in **`HomeScreenCompose`** (considering it's the root of the screens), or is it possible to implement it within **`HeaderCompose`** where the settings button resides?

My code is something like this.

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreenCompose(
    viewModel: HomeScreenViewModel = remember { HomeScreenViewModel() }
) {
    Column {
        // Header
        HeaderCompose()

        // Content
        MyContentView
    }
}
```

```
@Composable 
fun HeaderCompose(
    viewModel: HeaderViewModel = remember { HeaderViewModel() }
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(60.dp)
            .background(color = Color.Gray)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .height(60.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp, Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text("Home")
            
            SettingsButton(onTap = { 
                // TODO: want to display Detail View
            })
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun DetailScreenCompose(
    viewModel: DetailScreenViewModel = remember { DetailScreenViewModel() }
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        // todo display some text
    }
}
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You need to use ```NavHost``` to Switch Between Screens. You can refer a complete example of mine : https://medium.com/@chiragthummar16/jetpack-compose-navigation-best-practices-beginners-239794217b61